# Error on mapping an array of objects in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map an array i.e static json data  . Unable to map as I am getting error as this.props.movies.map is not a function. Below is the code for Table component with App.js. as the object in json file is movies.as I followed the same step on fetching api but was able to get data

import data from '../src/data.json'

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movies: data,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Table movies={this.state.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Table.css';
import { list } from 'postcss';

class Table extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { }
    }

    render() {
        const list = this.props.movies.map((movie) => (   
                <tr key={movie.Title}>
                    <td>{movie.Title}</td>
                    <td>{movie.Director}</td>
                </tr>
            )
         );

        return (
            <div className="table">
                table
               <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Director</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {list}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: What is the data? Without knowing the data how can you expect us to help you. Please share the data

Comment: Its a json file like this {
    "movies": [
        {
          "Title": "Django Unchained",
          "Year": "2012",
          "Rated": "UNRATED",
          "Released": "25 Dec 2012",

Comment: So you have to assign data.movies in the state like following this.state = {
      movies: data.movies,
    }

Comment: If your root key is "movies", then it should be this.state.movies.movies(data.movies). Am I right?

Comment: this.state = {
      movies: data.movies,
    }       this works

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your data contains movies array. So you need to assign data.movies to movies when you are initializing the state. Check below one for better understanding

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      movies: data.movies,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        {movies.length === 0 ? <h1>Loading Movies</h1> : <Table movies={this.state.movies} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is  const { movies } = this.state; required inside render

Comment: You can also directly access like this.state.movies but having const { movies } = this.state meaning helps reusability you no need to call this.state.movies every time and this is part of ES6. It works the same way for props as well like for eg const { data } = this.props;

Comment: Also kindly upvote my answer if it resolves your issue.